# Por que não consigo visualizar minhas Dags?

Tags: docker

Com este docker-compose eu executo minhas imagens locais no Windows.

```
version: "3.7"
x-airflow-environment: &airflow-environment
  AIRFLOW__CORE__AIRFLOW_HOME: /usr/local/airflow
  AIRFLOW__CORE__DAGS_FOLDER: /usr/local/airflow/dags
  AIRFLOW__CORE__BASE_LOG_FOLDER: /usr/local/airflow/logs
  AIRFLOW__CORE__EXECUTOR: LocalExecutor
  AIRFLOW__CORE__LOAD_EXAMPLES: "False"
  AIRFLOW__CORE__SQL_ALCHEMY_CONN: postgresql+psycopg2://airflow:airflow@postgres:5432/airflow
  AIRFLOW__CORE__FERNET_KEY: W2imcBfFi9Bjy0Xy-zBDg6v2Xhkf573CmNCOscx1Efc=
  AIRFLOW__DAG_DEFAULT_VIEW: graph
  
  

services:
  postgres:
    image: banco-post:nginx
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: airflow
      POSTGRES_DB: airflow
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: airflow
  init:
    image: init_1:nginx
    environment:
      <<: *airflow-environment
    depends_on:
      - postgres
    volumes:
      - ./dags:/usr/local/airflow/dags
      - ./plugins:/usr/local/airflow/plugins
      - ./logs:/usr/local/airflow/logs
    entrypoint: /bin/bash
    command: >
      -c "airflow list_users || (airflow initdb
      && airflow create_user --role Admin --username airflow --password airflow -e airflow@airflow.com -f airflow -l airflow)"
    restart: on-failure
  webserver:
    image: webserver:nginx
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
    environment:
      <<: *airflow-environment
    depends_on:
      - init
    volumes:
      - ./dags:/usr/local/airflow/dags
      - ./plugins:/usr/local/airflow/plugins
      - ./logs:/usr/local/airflow/
    entrypoint: /bin/bash
    command: -c "airflow webserver"
    restart: always
  scheduler:
    image: scheduler:nginx
    environment:
      <<: *airflow-environment
    depends_on:
      - webserver
    volumes:
      - ./dags:/usr/local/airflow/dags
      - ./plugins:/usr/local/airflow/plugins
      - ./logs:/usr/local/airflow/
    entrypoint: /bin/bash
    command: -c "airflow scheduler"
    restart: always
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O problema é que não consigo acessar pastas locais em meu Ubuntu 18.04 para carregar as DAGs.
Aqui estão as minhas DAGs no Ubuntu:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Aqui  pode-se ver que as DAGs não aparecem:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

É como se meus conteiners não “enxergassem” realmente a pasta local do Ubuntu. Como faço isso?

Answer (score 0):

1 - Na pasta onde está seu arquivo docker-compose, criar uma pasta chamada dags e colocar suas dags dentro desta pasta.

2 - No docker-compose, em volumes, compartilhar a pasta padrão do airflow com pasta local que contem suas dags:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Tudo irá funcionar.